# Printing numbers in a row without using string

Tags: python

I am new to python and I was practicing my coding skills with Hacker rank. I came across a question where I have to print numbers in a series one after another without adding any new line or white space in between them and most important is I cannot use the string method to get desired output.

For example if
input is

`3`

then output should be

`123`

How can do it without string?

Please guide me...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Python 2.7 or Python3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `end` keyword in `print()` method to avoid spaces:

```
num = int(input("Enter number: "))
for i in range(1, num+1):
    print(i, end='')
```

Comment: Supported on Python3

Comment: This answer is not supported in python 2. If anyone is getting error, check python version.

Comment: @ShivamSingh Fair point. But to be honest we should stop talking about python 2 all at once because it'll [die quite soon](https://pythonclock.org/).

Comment: @yevhenKuzmovych yea but i too came across the same question and after searching for the answer here, i found our that i wasn't working because python 2 compiler was selected. So i wrote this comment for people who doing it on online compilers where pyhton 2 is still an option.

Comment: One thing that bears explaining: the Hackerrank challenge in question specifies not using any string functions. Although this answer is easily found in a simple web search, it can look like a wrong answer because a lot of the articles refer to the empty quotation marks as an "empty string," which could look like it violates the no string functions requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You may create a custom function using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) along with the usage of [`math.log10()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log10) as:

```
import math

def get_my_number(num):
    my_num = 0
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        digits = int(math.log10(i))+1  # count number of digits in number
        my_num = my_num * (10 ** digits) + i
    return my_num
```

Sample run:

```
>>> get_my_number(3)
123
>>> get_my_number(13)  # For number greater than 10
12345678910111213
```

This way you will get the actual value and you won't be just printing it on the console

Comment: ok. so what is the method to work around for number more than 10

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

for statement below takes elements starting from 1 to n.

- If you use "in range(n)" it would print the elements starting from 0 to n-1.
- If you use "in range(1,n)" it would print the elements starting from 1 to n-1.
- If you use "in range(1,n+1)" it would print the elements starting from 0 to n. And this is what you want.

printing without new line requires and addition in print command.

- end = "" would print 123 for example.
- end = " " with 1 space between would print 1 2 3 and so on.

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      n = int(input())
      for i in range(1,n+1):
          print (i, end = "")
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input())

for i in range(n):    
    print(i+1, end="")
```

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation, in order to help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free coding service.

Comment: @AyushBasera Your proposed edit would make this code-only answer functionally identical to your code-only answer, which requires explanation. Also, editing other authors code with functional changes is not appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print n natural number without using string then you can try this code:

```
n=int(input())
print(*range(1,n+1),sep="")
```

simple input: 5
output will be: 12345

Answer (score 1):

The following copy integer values to array `ls` before writing to a buffer `pr` and making a single write call (print):

```
n = int(input())
ls = []
pr = ("")
for i in range(1,n+1):
    ls.append(i)
for i in range(len(ls)):
    pr += "{}".format(ls[i])
print(pr)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Comment: Please try to give some explanation.